# ActiveMQ vs AMQP .NET Lite versions

Tags: activemq-classic, amqp

ActiveMQ, as per [line 151 in AmqpWireFormat](http://activemq.apache.org/maven/5.14.4/apidocs/src-html/org/apache/activemq/transport/amqp/AmqpWireFormat.html), refuses connections with a AMQP protocol version other than 1.0.0.

AMQP .NET Lite, as per [line 411 in Connection](https://github.com/Azure/amqpnetlite/blob/master/src/Connection.cs#L411), sends 0.1.0.0. At the same time it claims to do [Full control of AMQP 1.0 protocol behavior](https://github.com/Azure/amqpnetlite).

Obviously ActiveMQ refuses connections from AMQP .NET Lite with "Connection attempt from non AMQP v1.0 client. AMQP,0,1,0,0".

The client does:

```
Address address = new Address("amqp://localhost:5672");
Connection connection = new Connection(address);
Session session = new Session(connection);
```

And ActiveMQ logs:

```
2017-03-28 09:11:28,403 | DEBUG | Transport Connection to: tcp://0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:54352 failed: org.apache.activemq.transport.amqp.AmqpProtocolException: Connection from client using unsupported AMQP attempted | org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection.Transport | ActiveMQ Transport: tcp:///0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:54352@5672
org.apache.activemq.transport.amqp.AmqpProtocolException: Connection from client using unsupported AMQP attempted
        at org.apache.activemq.transport.amqp.protocol.AmqpConnection.onAMQPData(AmqpConnection.java:339)[activemq-amqp-5.14.4.jar:5.14.4]
        at org.apache.activemq.transport.amqp.AmqpProtocolDiscriminator.onAMQPData(AmqpProtocolDiscriminator.java:96)[activemq-amqp-5.14.4.jar:5.14.4]
        at org.apache.activemq.transport.amqp.AmqpTransportFilter.onCommand(AmqpTransportFilter.java:107)[activemq-amqp-5.14.4.jar:5.14.4]
        at org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportSupport.doConsume(TransportSupport.java:83)[activemq-client-5.14.4.jar:5.14.4]
        at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.doRun(TcpTransport.java:233)[activemq-client-5.14.4.jar:5.14.4]
        at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.run(TcpTransport.java:215)[activemq-client-5.14.4.jar:5.14.4]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)[:1.8.0_112]
```

On the command line it says:

```
 WARN | Connection attempt from non AMQP v1.0 client. AMQP,0,1,0,0
```

ActiveMQ then aborts the connection.

The ActiveMQ configuration includes:

```
<transportConnectors>
    <transportConnector name="amqp" uri="amqp://0.0.0.0:5672" />
</transportConnectors>
```

This all looks to me like ActiveMQ expects version 1.0.0.0 and amqpnetlite sends 0.1.0.0.

Where to, from here?

Comment: Folks use the .NET lite client against ActiveMQ all the time, you need to provide some more information as the code all looks correct to me

Comment: Added some info to the question... Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default ActiveMQ requires authentication. try

```
string queueName = "q1";
Connection connection = new Connection(new Address("amqp://user:pwd@localhost:5672"));
Session session = new Session(connection);
SenderLink sender = new SenderLink(session, "sender", queueName);
Message message = new Message("Hello World");
sender.Send(message);
connection.Close();
```

The user name and password should be in users.properties config file. Also it is recommended to use async API to avoid blocking I/O calls.

Comment: Yes that was it.

It would help if ActiveMQ logged what the problem is. The method has three cases where it returns false (bad), and doesn't provide a way of logging what the issue is.

Answer (score 0):

Both ActiveMQ and AMQP .NET Lite support the ISO/IEC Standard 1.0 version of AMQP. The protocol header "AMQP0100" indicates version 1.0 of the protocol. AMQP .NET Lite is known to work with ActiveMQ so I suspect you have some other configuration issue.

Comment: Thanks, I've added some info to the question... It looks to me like ActiveMQ expects version 1.0.0.0 and amqpnetlite sends 0.1.0.0. What am I missing I wonder?

Answer (score 0):

My assumption is that you haven't turned off the broker's enforcement of requiring the client to connect via a SASL handshake either via SASL anonymous or SASL plain depending on whether you've configured a real authentication plugin or not.  I would bet that if you configured the broker by adding the options `wireFormat.allowNonSaslConnections=true` that it would probably work.

From the information you've provided the .NET client is not using SASL so the broker is rejecting it.  The SASL header would be "AMQP3100"

Comment: This, or authentication --> http://stackoverflow.com/a/43057456/2875848